# Service Fabric - storing a List<T> in StateManager for a reliable actor

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

One of my use cases requires storing all events between "start" and a "stop" events from a single event producer. We will be using a reliable actor to process this data and summarize after "stop" event is received. The straight forward way to store all events between start and stop is in a type List.

```
// Init
var evts = new List<DataEvent>();
this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync("events", evts);

// Fetch, add and save
var evts = this.StateManager.TryGetStateAsync<List<DataEvent>>("events");
evts.Add(newEvent);
this.StateManager.TrySaveStateAsync("events", evts);
```

From my understanding every time I fetch the existing list, add a new item and store the new updated list the StateManager will serialize/deserialize the whole array. Is my understanding correct?

And what would be a good alternative to this solution?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The best approach is to treat state manager as it is - key value storage, and partition your different streams by the key that could be composite.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. My streams are partitioned and each actor will handle one device, however I need to store a series of events in each actor to be able to calculate a summary.

Answer (score 2):

Following recommendations from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-state-management):

> A "save" can include persisting to disk and replication, depending on
>   the settings used. Values that have not been modified are not
>   persisted or replicated. If no values have been modified, the save
>   operation does nothing.

I'd recommend using an Immutable collection like [ImmutableList](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.EventDriven/blob/MoreListeners/CustomerOrdersActor.Interfaces/ICustomerOrdersActor.cs#L25) instead of List, or your changes may end up being in memory only.

Comment: That's a very good point. ATM I am thinking of having one state key per array element and keep element counter in a state. I will also have a local copy of the array so the only time I need to read this state array element by element is if an actor is activated due to some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using two actor-types:

- DeviceActor
- EventActor

Your device-actor can recieve events, create one new EventActor for each event (with stores verbose information about each event) and keep a HashSet in your DeviceActor-state, one per EventActor.

Alternativly, if you need a bit more information to filter the events on: a Dictionary, or a tuple if you need more information directly in the DeviceActor without calling it's subactors.